# Not able to login with ssh in AWS ec2 bitnami Instance

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I am not able to login with AWS ec2 Bitnami instance.

I have created new keypair for the ec2-instance and i have converted the keypair into ppk with the puttygen.

I have tried to use the login with the different user name like bitnami, ec2-user, ubuntu, root but i cant get any success i have read many blogs amazon document, bitnami document but and apply there that process but still not get success.

I have created new user group  and provided access for the ssh, http, https with there defult port.

Server Details.

Instance type : m1.small

Description : https://bitnami.com
Status : available
Platform : Ubuntu
Image Size : 10GB
Visibility : Public

bitnami-magento-1.9.0.1-0-linux-ubuntu-12.04.4-x86_64-ebs

Whenever i am trying to login with the ssh i get the error message.

Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your public key file is got some issue. I am guessing it should be the puTTY bug which requires an extra newline character at the end of the key file.

When creating the public key, open it in puTTYgen and copy and paste (this will make the key to be formatted in one line along with a newline) it to your `authorized_keys` and try to login.

For more information, read a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204400/ssh-public-key-no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent-publ)

Comment: HI Robert, I have used the puTTYgen for copy and past the key.

Comment: Hi Robert, I have used the puTTYgen for copy and past the key. and used for the login but still not able to login to the server.